# Get latest file SHA given filename of changed files in push

Tags: github-actions

Hello I'm a little confused if it is possible via Github Actions to get the latest SHA of a file with only its file's name.

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions

name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on push or pull request events but only for the master branch
  push:
    branches: [ master ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      # Checks-out your repository under $GITHUB_WORKSPACE, so your job can access it
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          
      - name: Get specific changed files
        id: changed-files-specific
        uses: tj-actions/changed-files@v15.1
        with:
          files: |
            *.groovy
          files_ignore: |
            *.yml
            
        # Runs a set of commands using the runners shell
      - name: echo changed files
        run: |
          echo modified files ---
          echo ${{steps.changed-files-specific.outputs.modified_files}}
```

As you can see with the combination of action `changed-files-specific` and `echo changed files` I am able to get the filename. I looked at the documentation of the tj-actions/changed-files library and it does not provide file info support.

Is there an easy way to do this? I tried searching for another action library but it does not seem to be a very common use case.

Many Thanks,
Morgan Morningstar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track.

Now when you have all the modified files and their paths - you can just easily do whatever you want with those files.

You can iterate over those files and calculate SHA for each of them using those paths.

Something like this:

```
for file in ${{ steps. changed-files-specific.outputs.modified_files }}; do
    sha=`sha1sum $file | cut -d ' ' -f 1`
    echo "sha for $file: $sha"
done
```